# Does Google Chrome extensions webNavigation API's URL filter support negation?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Seems like it doesn't support negation natively, for example it has `hostContains` or `urlContains` but it doesn't have `hostNotConatins` etc. So I resorted to use regular expressions, and now to my surprise, when I use `?!` Regex negation, Chrome fails to add the listener and returns error:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: 'js/contentScript.js'
    });
},{url: [{urlMatches: "/(?!(downloads))"}]});
```

Why is this? Why are they limiting what we can do on URL filters? JS natively supports Regex `?!` negation.

Or am I doing it wrong? Is there any workaround?

Comment: There's no way to use exclusions in filters. As the documentation says, the API uses RE2 syntax which doesn't have negative look-ahead for performance reasons.

Comment: I was thinking to use `location.href.search(/[\/](?!(downloads))/) From a background script, but I don't have access to `location.href` there, so I thought maybe I can use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` from the contentScript to the background script but it doesn't work. So I don't know what options I have, do you know any? Thanks

Comment: See the documentation: listener receives a details parameter with url inside.

Comment: Do you mean `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`? But I'm using content scripts declared in manifest and using webNavigation to re inject them, using `onUpdated` breaks the whole point. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Why onUpdated? I mean the listener in your code of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User wOxxOm answered my question in the comments and I was hoping he would write an answer at the end so I could mark this question as answered but he didn't, so I had to copy his answer:

If the built in url filter is not enough, the `webNavigation` listener has an object parameter for it's callback function which holds the url of the page, you can do your filters on it like this:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(obj){
    if (obj["url"].search(/twitch.tv[\/](?!(directory|downloads|friends|inventory|jobs|p|payments|settings|subscriptions|turbo))/) > 0){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            file: 'js/twitchContentScript2.js'
        });
    }
},{url: [{hostSuffix: "twitch.tv", urlMatches: "((.+://)?(www\.)?twitch.tv/.+$)"}]});
```

Here are the comments for documentation, if someone thinks this is unnecessary, please let me know by editing them out:

> There's no way to use exclusions in filters. As the documentation
>   says, the API uses RE2 syntax which doesn't have negative look-ahead
>   for performance reasons. – wOxxOm Jan 12 at 17:07
>
> I was thinking to use `location.href.search(/[\/](?!(downloads))/)`
>   From a background script, but I don't have access to `location.href`
>   there, so I thought maybe I can use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` from
>   the `contentScript` to the background script but it doesn't work. So I
>   don't know what options I have, do you know any? Thanks – Shayan Jan
>   12 at 18:45
>
> See the documentation: listener receives a details parameter with url
>   inside. – wOxxOm Jan 12 at 18:54
>
> Do you mean `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`? But I'm using content scripts
>   declared in manifest and using `webNavigation` to re inject them,
>   using `onUpdated` breaks the whole point. Or do you mean something
>   else? – Shayan Jan 12 at 19:00
>
> Why onUpdated? I mean the listener in your code of course. – wOxxOm
>   Jan 12 at 19:02